# Check if a category exists Shopware 6

Tags: php, shopify, shopware, shopware6

Check if a category exists`your text`

I have such code

```
 $categoryService = $this->container->get('category.repository');
    $newCategory = [
            'name' => 'Profi-Shop',
            'parentId' => null,
            'customFields' => [
        ],
    ];

    $categoryService->create([$newCategory], $context->getContext());
```

It is executed every time. How to execute it only if there is no such category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if your category exists prior creating it. If it does, then just skip creation step:

```php
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;

$categoryService = $this->container->get('category.repository');
$newCategoryName = 'Profi-Shop';

// Search for the category first
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', $newCategoryName));
$existingCategory = $categoryService->search($criteria, $context->getContext());

// Create it if there's no match found:
if ($existingCategory->getTotal() === 0) {
    $newCategory = [
        'name' => $newCategoryName,
        'parentId' => null,
        'customFields' => [],
    ];

    $categoryService->create([$newCategory], $context->getContext());
}
```

Comment: And how can you access this category in twig later? Since it will be needed almost everywhere. Thus it would not be desirable to address very explicitly. Call by id or name will not go away